# webdav, controlling access to folder

Tags: linux, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, apache-2.4, webdav

In the root (/var/www/webdav/) of my webdav share I have two folders:

```
valid
myuser
```

I would like the `valid` folder to be accessible to any valid-user. So I did:

```
Alias /webdav /var/www/webdav/
<Location /webdav>
    DAV On
    AuthType Digest
    AuthName "webdav"
    AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/users.password
    Require valid-user
</Location>
```

and, I would like `myuser` folder only accessible to `myuser`, so:

```
Alias /myuser /var/www/webdav/myuser
<Location /myuser>
    DAV On
    AuthType Digest
    AuthName "webdav"
    AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/users.password
    Require user myuser
</Location>
```

Problem: Another user (not myuser) is getting access to webdav/myuser/.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Is the user getting access to `http://example.org/webdav/myuser` or to `http://example.org/myuser`?

Comment: http://example.org/webdav/myuser, since http://example.org/myuser does not exist.

Answer (score 2):

`<Location>` matches URLS, so the URL `webdav/myuser` is only covered by the first rule with the more permissive restriction. You would need to either change to `<Directory>` or change the second block to `<Location /webdav/myuser>`

Comment: I full answer would be highly appreciated, including source code.

Comment: This is a full answer.

Comment: The order should matter?

Comment: Alias should be changed to `Alias /webdav/cristiano`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm still curious about how the `<Directory>` approach would be used by @Sven.

But the following seems to solve the issue:

```
Alias /webdav /var/www/webdav/
<Location /webdav>
    DAV On
    AuthType Digest
    AuthName "webdav"
    AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/users.password
    Require valid-user
</Location>

Alias /webdav/myuser /var/www/webdav/myuser
<Location /webdav/myuser>
    DAV On
    AuthType Digest
    AuthName "webdav"
    AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/users.password
    Require user myuser
</Location>
```

Comment: Read https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/sections.html to learn about the differences between `<Location>` and `<Directory>`.